# Cannot extract data from XML file using XMLStarlet in the command line (namespace restriction)

Tags: command-line, xmlstarlet

I try to extract data from a xml file (which I named output.xml) on the command line (and then, if I manage to do it, put it in a script).

I've seen that the better tool to do that is XMLStarlet. However `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/entry/content" output.xml` doesn't work.

Note: I tried for `xmlstarlet el output.xml` to check the Xpath structure of the file and it works.That means that the tool sees the elements.

---

I saw that there are 2 conditions to make XMLStarlet work:

1- The XML file should be well-formed. [Stackoverflow related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669280/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-elements-in-an-xml-document-using-xmlstarlet-in-ba)

So I applied this command to create a well-formed file:

`xmlstarlet fo -R output.xml >> good-output.xml`

2- XML is very picky about the default namespace. If the document has it, declare it before selecting the elements or delete all the occurences of "xmlns" in the document. [Stackoverflow related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025492/xmlstarlet-does-not-select-anything)

So I did:

`$ cat good-output.xml | sed -e 's/ xmlns.*=".*"//g' >> very-good-output.xml`

HOWEVER, even performing these two steps, I have another error, and  don't know how to fix it... The terminal points to me the places I removed the namespaces and says "Namespace prefix app on collection is not defined". What I should do? With the namespaces it doesn't work and now it urges to put them again upon me...

Any help?

[Screenshot of the original problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AbAo.png)

[Screenshot of the final problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTU4x.png)

Comment: Okay, maybe I've understood why the terminal is blaming me. The tags where there is the error are formed like so: 

`word:anotherword` 

And it seems that this notation implies that we should find a xmlns attribute in that tag. But I don't know how I can delete these notations. I guess I have to use REGEX but I'm still not comfortable with it to do such action.

Comment: If your document defines the namespaces you can use its prefixes in the XPath expressions, see also http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html.

Comment: Thank you! I used `xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//_:content" -c . good-output.xml` and it gave me the corresponding tag. The only problem now is that I only want the content of the tag and not the tag itself + its content. How should I do?

Comment: `-v` instead of `-c`.

Comment: Yes it works. It works with `/text()` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is the final solution to retrieve the content of a XML file with multiple namespaces:

`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//_:content" -c . good-output.xml`

---

npostavs thank you for guiding me.

I believed the fact that my first attempt gave me the tag besides the desired content was a problem, but actually in my case no. If it is the case for someone else, this is how to proceed:

`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/_:entry/_:content/text()" -c . output.xml`

OR

`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/_:entry/_:content" -v . output.xml`

Simplified:

`xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/_:entry/_:content" output.xml`

Comment: You could possibly simplify that to `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/_:entry/_:content" output.xml`

Comment: Tested, it works too, thank you :) I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problems like this happens if the xml uses a different namespace. In these cases, one solution to overcome namespaces issues is to tell `xmlstarlet` the expected namespace value of the element:

`xmlstarlet sel -N x='http://different.namespace.url/XMLSchema' -t -m '//x:YourElemHere' input.xml`